# Regex: how to match anything before and after uppercase sequences with a period as delimiter?

Tags: regex

I have a series of sentences containing uppercase keywords in a large text containing several other sentences. I just need to match those sentences that contain uppercase words (1 or more), for instance:

```
This is MY SENTENCE that should be matched.
And THIS one should be too.
This other sentence should not be matched.
```

Any suggestion? Thanks! I am not an advanced user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is it:

```
^.*\b[A-Z]+\b.*$
```

- \b assert position at a word boundary
- A-Z a single character in the range between A (index 65) and Z

https://regex101.com/r/kUN41W/1

---

If `I` is NOT counted as an UPPERCASE word in a sentence that matches your conditions. Then use this:

```
^.*\b[A-Z]{2,}\b.*$
```

- {2,} Quantifier — Matches between 2 and unlimited times, as many
  times as possible, giving back as needed

Comment: Great! It worked... I only had to tick the 'case' option in Notepad++ to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Try some tools like https://regexr.com/. They really help visualizing which effect your regex has.

For your testdata this regex is fine:

```
([^\.]*[A-Z]{2,}[^\.]*)\.
```

It is composed of

- `[^\.]*` anything that is no dot
- `[A-Z]{2,}` at least 2 uppercase characters
- `[^\.]*` anything that is no dot

Answer (score 0):

using `Python`

```
import re

txt = 'This is MY SENTENCE and I would like, this sentence, to be matched because it contains uppercase words. This other sentence should not be matched. And THIS one should be.' 

for s in txt.split('.'):
    if re.search(r'\b[A-Z]+\b', s): 
        print(s)
```

output:

> ```
> This is MY SENTENCE and I would like, this sentence, to be matched because it contains uppercase words
>  And THIS one should be
> ```